# Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4.7, Windows 10 can't load cURL Extension from Apache Service but loads fine from Command Line with httpd

Tags: php, windows, apache, curl, localhost

I have been fighting this problem for 2 days now and can't seem to solve it.
I installed Apache on my computer and am running as localhost. I do not have SSL but have tried with and without loading openssl extension.
If I start the Apache 24 Service from "Windows Services" PHP works but no extension dlls will be loaded, specifically I'm trying to load cURL.  If I stop the "Windows Services" and run httpd from a command prompt all of the extensions load just fine.

Interestingly enough all PHP functionality works fine except the extensions when running from the "Windows Services".

The event log shows the following when I first start the "Apache Windows Service":

```
php[29280] 
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl' (tried: ext\php_curl (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) (D:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -d D:/Apache24)
```

The only real clue I have found in the phpinfo is the difference I see between the "Windows Service" and the Command Line httpd is:

**"Windows Service"**

[image]

**"Command Line httpd"**

[image]

My php.ini file has the following settings for cURL:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=curl
extension=openssl
```

**PHP Info Screen Shots:**

**Common to Both**

[image]

**Using command line "httpd"**

[image]

**Using Windows Service (Note cURL is missing and event log shows the error mentioned above)**

[image]

I also noticed the "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" is set to "C:\Windows" so I tried copying the php.ini file to c:\windows and copied the ext folder containing all of the dlls to C:\Windows as well but still had the exact same problem.  I have since removed the php.ini and ext folder from C:\Windows to avoid any future path problems.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've been battling this for a few days. Hadn't thought to run from console. Still don't have a solution, but at least I can focus on troubleshooting the service.

Answer (score 1):

Define the path of the extention directory to full path from

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

to

```
extension_dir = "c:\PHP7.4.7\ext"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Jean, that was the first thing I tried but the symptom remains the same.

Comment: @LarryRobertson Can you add your Apache configuration related to PHP ?

Comment: i am using slash instead backslash and it is work. extension_dir = "c:/PHP7.4.7/ext"

Answer (score 1):

If correcting paths in Apache and PHP configuration files doesn't correct the issue, be sure you've added your PHP install location to the system's ENVIRONMENT PATH variable.

I had added PHP's path to my account's PATH environment variable, not the system's. This explains why the Apache HTTPD Windows Service running as the Local System account fails to find some PHP extensions but httpd.exe started via CLI as me did find the extensions.

Comment: Thank you Chad, its been a while since this post but I did have the path in the environment variable.  I have since purchased a new computer and no longer have the dll issues with Apache.